# MVVM-light There is already a factory registered for INavigationService

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm-light

I'm trying to adjust my WP8 project from self made MVVM implementation to MVVM Light.

The application compiles without errors, but when I open my MainPage.xaml in Expression Blend, I will get this error:

Class project.Services.INavigationService is already registered. App.xaml

My ViewModelLocator.cs:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the ViewModelLocator class.
    /// </summary>
    public ViewModelLocator()
    {
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

        if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            if (!SimpleIoc.Default.IsRegistered<INavigationService>())
            {
                SimpleIoc.Default.Register<INavigationService>(() => new NavigationService());
            }
        }

        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainPage>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<SettingsEditViewModel>();
    }
```

As you can see from my code comment, I've already tried the fix supposed here, but I'm still getting this error in Blend. There is no other place left where I could register the INavigationService, so what could be the problem?

Any ideas? :)

Answer (score 18):

I had the same issue, and this seems to be a Visual Studio issue in combination with XAML-Designer, Static Factories/Locators and Design-Time creation of objects. However: The solutions were the following:

1. Register without a factory (not recommended)

   `SimpleIoc.Default.Register<INavigationService>();`
2. Or if you want to use a factory, unregister before registering the factory

   `SimpleIoc.Default.Unregister<INavigationService>();`
   `SimpleIoc.Default.Register<INavigationService>(() => new NavigationService());`
3. Prevent the ViewModelLocator from being created more than once by the designer/Blend by making the constructor static

   `static ViewModelLocator() { ... }`

The error is cumbersome but could happen in this scenario: You create objects during design-time (the `ViewModelLocator` within App.xaml probably) and whenever you change something in your Code, the Compiler is triggered and the ViewModelLocator gets re-created without ever unregistering the services. Therefore it will complain that in the factory has already been registered. In theory, when registering classes without factories multiple times, there should be an error as-well.

Comment: I ended up making my ViewModelLocator looking like this: http://i.imgur.com/2Ex0rzy.png Simply exits out of the initialization, in case the VS designer thinks it's a good idea to construct it again in design time. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: 3rd choice of making the constructor of the `ViewModelLocator` static worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Might already be solved by now, but I think you can just solve the issue in your example case by not using the factory method override.

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<INavigationService, NavigationService>();
```

If you do need a factory method, then you can mix this line in with your factory method approach using the design mode check like you have been.

```
if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
{
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<INavigationService, NavigationService>();
}
else
{
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<INavigationService>(CreateNavigationService);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a super old question, but after hours of googling, this is the only question that's similar to my problem, so answering here for other people.

Make sure that you have IsDataSource on your ViewModelLocator:

```
<vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" d:IsDataSource="True" />
```

That solved my problem and my design data popped up straightaway.

Weirdly, after putting that on, all my "INavigationService is already registered" errors goes away!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why, but I only get this error when my xaml designer window is open.  When I compile with it closed, the error goes away and the project is built and runs successfully.